# Does Expression Engine have a database abstraction layer or API?

Tags: php, sql, expressionengine

It seems that the only way to get entries out of EE is to use template tags or write SQL. I'd rather not write SQL since it's not very portable. I would expect EE to have some DAL so I could do something like:

```
// load entry of type "Post" with id 15
$this->EE->db->loadEntry('post',15);
```

Is SQL the only option to access data from PHP?

Comment: Turns out the secret lies within the Code Ingiter docs: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html#select

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following library, created by objectivehtml: 
https://github.com/objectivehtml/Channel-Data

Of course, the best would be to have an API directly available in the EE core, but the existing one (Api_channel_entries) seems to only allow the creation or update of entries.